# Are SoundCloud API rate limits per client ID or per browser/device?

Tags: soundcloud

Rate limits have been introduced, as discussed here:

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits

It is not clear what "client application" means in this context.  Is the rate limit per client ID or per unique browser/device?

Comment: This is less of a programming question, and more of a question for SoundCloud support.

Comment: @JAL unfortunately, SoundCloud seems to be using SO as it's own personal support forum: https://developers.soundcloud.com/support

Comment: Doesn't mean users should ask non-programming questions here.  Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: @JAL i think it's a little unfair to down vote a question considering SoundCloud are using this as a forum -- their own developers are answering many of the questions (1,590 tagged currently).  Also, I would argue an API-related question is a programming topic.  See also Facebook API questions (24,000 questions and counting).

Answer (score 0):

A "client application" refers to an individual application under your developer account on soundcloud.com. Each client application has a set of client credentials, which consist of a client id and client secret pair.

The rate limits are currently being determined per client id, although this may change in the future.